# When did Lego switch from 4 to 6 stud width of Windscreen?

Tags: history, city

All my old sets have cars with windscreen 4 studs wide. No matter if it is a jeep, truck or what - cars was 4 studs, usually [3823](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3823) or [2437](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2437). Now, in most modern sets, car windshield is usually 6 studs wide, like [92583](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92583#T=P).

I'm interested when this transition happened. If it's possible, I'll be also glad to hear why - was this change caused by introduction of other bricks? New "series" of a City theme? General overhaul?

Comment: Both windscreens you mention are still in production. Apart from that, the appearence of LEGO models has changed dramatically over the years. I don't think that a transition of any sort can be pinned to the introduction of certain new parts. The number of new parts increases every year, so in 10 years today's sets may look old and clumsy.

Comment: @Aziraphale are still in production, but now 4 studs one is used for totally different models it used to. And while overall change is continuous, there must've been a point where "truck width"  switched from 4 to 6.

Comment: Realism seems to be the most probable answer. If you compare the Tow Trucks 6656 (1985) and 7638 (2009) it is clear that proportions and shapes have improved by orders of magnitude. Thinking about it: Stud width and minifig size are constants, everything else could change. So it was only natural to increase vehicle width by 2 studs.

Comment: The lego trains from the 1970's and 80's all started with 6 stud width designs.

Comment: @LarsTech nice catch. I mean to ask about cars specifically, but now I see I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this, too. But only after the "Speed Champions" came out a few years ago. (I didn't give much attention to CITY.) It seems to me like the LEGO Racers got wider, more detailed sets starting from 2008 or so.

Also: I often check the Bricklink inventory part page (example: [92583](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92583#T=P)), to find the **Years Released** under the "**Item Info**" section. I cross reference those dates with the list of sets that an item was used in.